# remove punctuation from a certain part of string

Tags: r, regex

I have vectors

```
a1 = "Hello, Mr. R.A. Ivanov, nice to see you here " 
a2 = "Mr. R.A.Ivanov, did you attend the concert last night"
a3 = "I finally met you Mr.R.A.Ivanov"
```

I want to delete punctuation from the part `"Mr. R.A. Ivanov"` and to have only `"Mr R A Ivanov"` in the string. So, my output would be:

```
a1 ="Hello, Mr R A Ivanov, nice to see you here"
```

Also, as can be noticed, there are sometimes spaces between letters, sometimes not. And I don't know how to deal with it too.

Comment: What's the general rule for removing periods? I can't generalize your specific example. How should R tell the difference between what should be removed and what should not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with `gsub`

```
gsub("\\b(Mr|[A-Z])\\.", "\\1 ", a1)
```

Comment: thank you! I have started learning regex, can you advise any tutorials?

Comment: @AinaNurmagombetova You might try [Perl Regular Expressions by Example](http://www.somacon.com/p127.php)